# Simplification step $\frac{\cosh(\theta)+1}{\cosh(\theta)-1}$ to $\left (\frac{1+e^{-\theta}}{1-e^{-\theta}}\right )^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a proof, part of a formula is simplified from: 
$\frac{\cosh(\theta)+1}{\cosh(\theta)-1}$ to $\left (\frac{1+e^{-\theta}}{1-e^{-\theta}}\right )^2$. I'm confused by where the extra $\pm e^{-\theta}$ came from in the numerator:
$$\frac{\cosh(\theta)+1}{\cosh(\theta)-1}$$
$$=\frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}+1}{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}-1}$$
$$=\frac{1+e^{-2\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{1+e^{-2\theta}-e^{-\theta}}$$
$$\ne\frac{1+e^{-2\theta}+2e^{-\theta}}{1+e^{-2\theta}-2e^{-\theta}}$$

The final value in the proof is correct, so I'm confused about the difference.

Comment: I would start with the RHS.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown The final formula is the right hand side squared. I also tried completing the square $=\frac{(e^{\theta/2}+e^{-\theta/2})^2-1}{(e^{\theta/2}+e^{-\theta/2})^2+1}$ Which doesn't help.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that $\cosh\theta=e^\theta+e^{-\theta}$ instead of $\dfrac{e^\theta+e^{-\theta}}2$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli lol, that was it. The two doesn't cancel with the constant term. I should always write it down on paper, rather than making mental steps. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a Little error, we have $$\frac{\cosh(x)+1}{\cosh(x)-1}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})+1}{\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})-1}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}+2}{e^x+e^{-x}-2}$$
and now multiply numerator and denominator by $e^x$